# Environment Variables and localization

Tags: c, windows, winapi, localization, environment-variables

There does not seem to be any documentation about this in MSDN but apparently SetEnvironmentVariableA and GetEnvironmentVariableA seem to work differently with special characters depending on the localization and I was wondering if this was expected.

I put together this simple C console program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    PUCHAR binIn = "\x06\xC7\x86\xC1\x99\x93\xCF";
    UCHAR binUt[16] = {0};
    SetEnvironmentVariable("MYVAR", binIn);
    GetEnvironmentVariable("MYVAR", binUt, 16);
    printf("%X %X %X %X %X %X %X\n", binUt[0], binUt[0], binUt[1], binUt[2], binUt[3], binUt[4], binUt[5], binUt[6]);
}
```

When run with System Locale as English, it displays the same bytes coming out as going in, i.e.:

```
06 C7 86 C1 99 93 CF
```

However, when run with System Locale as Japanese it displays slightly different output:

```
06 C7 81 45 99 93 CF
```

Is this expected? Is there a way to get it to return the same value regardless of the Locale?

Comment: Interesting: I cannot find any documentation anywhere that Set/GetEnvironmentVariable is affected by Localization, but apparently it is.

Comment: The *real* issue is, that you are calling the ANSI versions of API calls. Unless you absolutely must support Win9x, use the Unicode versions (with a trailing `W` character). They are cheaper to call, don't impose arbitrary length limits on their arguments, and just work as you'd expect them to. Notably, since Unicode encodings do not rely on the currently active locale, they exhibit identical behavior across different systems with different locales. Unlike ANSI encoding.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that there was some double secret way of getting it to work using only the ANSI versions, but apparently there isn't. I might have painted myself into a corner.

Comment: There is no reliable way to get this to work using ANSI encoding. You don't control the user's environment, and they may just be using values with characters, that cannot be represented in the currently active ANSI code page. Besides that, ANSI encoding does not provide a self-contained representation. It always relies on a code page. Unicode encodings (like UTF-16LE), on the other hand, are self-contained, and can represent *any* code point there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently some characters are not supported in this string. You can duplicate the problem by converting the string to UTF16 and back:

```
wchar_t* get_unicode(const char* ansi, UINT codepage)
{
    if(!ansi) return 0;
    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, ansi, -1, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* unicode = malloc(size * sizeof(wchar_t));
    MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, ansi, -1, unicode, size);
    return unicode;
}

char* get_char(const wchar_t* unicode, UINT codepage)
{
    if(!unicode) return 0;
    int size = WideCharToMultiByte(codepage, 0, unicode, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    char* ansi = malloc(size);
    WideCharToMultiByte(codepage, 0, unicode, -1, ansi, size, 0, 0);
    return ansi;
}

int main()
{
    //932 for Japanese code page
    wchar_t* unicode = get_unicode("\x06\xC7\x86\xC1\x99\x93\xCF", 932);
    char* ansi = get_char(unicode, 932);
    for(int i = 0, len = strlen(ansi); i < len; i++)
        printf("%02X ", ansi[i]&0xFF);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It's the same wrong result:

```
06 C7 81 45 99 93 CF
```

There might not be much you can do here. Maybe the original Japanese string was not converted properly, or maybe some characters are not supported.

Use Unicode to easily solve the problem:

```
int main()
{
    SetEnvironmentVariableW(L"MYVAR", L"日本語 ελληνικά");
    wchar_t buf[100];
    GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"MYVAR", buf, _countof(buf));
    MessageBoxW(0, buf, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

If the rest of your program is not Unicode or cannot be converted, you can store the wide char string in UTF8 format instead of UTF16, like the example below:

```
int main()
{
    char* utf8 = get_char(L"日本語", CP_UTF8);

    wchar_t* unicode = get_unicode(utf8, CP_UTF8);
    SetEnvironmentVariableW(L"MYVAR", unicode);
    wchar_t buf[100];
    GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"MYVAR", buf, _countof(buf));

    MessageBoxW(0, buf, 0, 0);

    free(utf8);
    free(unicode);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It gets stranger and stranger even with US localization. Let's say I have this input:  
    `PUCHAR binIn = "/x80/x81/x82.../x8F";`  
    `SetEnvironmentVariableA("MYVAR", binIn);`  
    `GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"MYVAR", binUt, SZ);`  
You'd expect the output to be something like this:  
    `8000810082008300....`  
But in fact it is completely different:  
    `AC2081001A209201...`

Comment: If `binUt` is `UCHAR` as parameter for `GetEnvironmentVariableW`, the C compiler gives warning (C++ compiler gives error) You are forcing a cast between `char` and `wchar_t`. UTF16 is complicated, it's sometimes 2 bytes per code point, sometimes 4 bytes. If `SetEnvironmentVariableA` was used, then only `GetEnvironmentVariableA` will retrieve the original bytes correctly. You might try `MultiByteToWideChar` with different code page (other than 932 which I guessed) But I think the error goes back to `SetEnvironmentVariableA` which didn't store the string correctly.